# Upgrading phpmyadmin (and other packages) on Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, debian

I just setup a new VM with Debian Squeeze (latest stable release, 6.0.4). I am going for a webserver, so I installed the usual... apache, php5, mysql, phpmyadmin, etc.

Everything went well, everything is working.

My question is about upgrading packages. I noticed the phpmyadmin version is 3.3.7... the latest is 3.4.10.1. Doing apt-get update/upgrade does not upgrade the package.

How does one go about upgrading packages on a Debian Squeeze server if apt-get update/upgrade does not work?

Thanks!

Comment: You either install the packages manually or you add a repo to the list of repos that apt uses.  (For phpmyadmin, I'd probably just do it manually.)  Also, as this is not a programming question, it does not belong on StackOverflow.  It belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download the latest version from the [official page](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and follow the instrucctions inside the compress file for the installation.

Alternatively if you want to use the debian repositories, you can add

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

in the file /etc/apt/source.list

Also add

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=testing
Pin-Priority: 500
```

in /etc/apt/preferences

doing this you will have all the packages for the testing version, but they're not going to be installed unless you specify it, so run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

for example

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin=3.4.10.1-1
```

you can check the different versions with

```
apt-cache showpkg phpmyadmin
```